# C# Controling a Form using another thread, also prevent from duplicating forms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, invoke

first of all, i am sorry that even if there's many given topic that may be related to my problem still i cant figure out how to solve my problem..

its just that most of the words used in the coding is new to me.
i really need your guidance guys.. =(

on to my problem..

i have 2 forms im my project.
the form1 is acting as my Login Screen
and form2 is will open if the users login is correct

im using UDP as my connection socket. i made a simple UDPlistener
inside a Timer(*reason is because if i dont close it if theres nothing to read,it will just
make my program hangs, and still keep on waiting for messages*)

Note: my UDP listener is being run on a different thread like this

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(UDPListener.StartListener);
thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
Thread.Sleep(100);
thread1.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

thread1.Start();
```

when the Server Program sends me a signal to Open up form2
the problem now occur..

the problem is.. form2 showed up.. but form1 didn't hide or visible=false; (*form1 need to be able to do that*)

im doing this code when im trying to show form2 and hide form1
Note: also another problem is (not really sure) .. i notice its just duplicating the forms

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f1.Command("009");
f1.MiniTicker.Enabled = false; //need to do this, cant do this without putting Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Login.TBOption.showTaskBar();
TaskbarHide.Taskbar.Hide();
f1.CoreAds.Enabled = false; //same here

f1.Visible = false;
f1.Hide();

f1.Invoke(
(MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
new TimerMode().Show();
}));


f1.Invoke(
(MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
new MainForm().Hide();
}));
```

Final Note: after i run the code above.. the Form1 is like closing, but after that it open up again...

please help me solve my problem. i need to finish my thesis project =(

Comment: im still encountering this problem.. =(

Comment: As a matter of coding practise, it's not wise to name your forms Form1 and Form2, but rather give them a descriptive name. Why not LoginForm and MainForm (or something even more descriptive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that the second batch of code is executing on the thread you created in the first batch. If that is the case then most of your problems arise because you are accessing UI elements from the worker thread. Let me make this perfectly clear. The only thing you can do with a `Form` or `Control` from a worker thread is call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`. That is it. You absolutely cannot do anything else.

- You cannot call a `Form` constructor.
- You cannot set the `Form.Visible` property.
- You cannot call `Form.Hide`.
- You cannot access *anything* relating to or contained within the `Form`.

This is worth repeating. With the exception of the `ISynchronizeInvoke` methods there is nothing else you can use on a `Form` reference from a worker thread. If you do attempt to access any UI element from a thread other than the main UI thread then your application will fail; sometimes unpredictably and sometimes spectacularly.

Comment: hi. brian im really thankful for your explanation. even if its kinda sad it cannot do it.. im thinking now. in what other way can i solve this problem.. do you think i need to change my Listener(udp)? i remember its the reason why made this problem. why i put those code in another thread.Brian really thanks i learn something new